# How do I download Yosemite on my imac?

Tags: macos, imac

I have an iMac (newer than 2007),and I need to run this year's version of Turbo Tax.  I am getting a message indicating that my current OS X, which is 10.6.8, is not sufficient to run this year's Turbo Tax (premier version).

I have tried to download Yosemite and have been unsuccessful.  I assume that once I download a new OS, that it will appear in place of the 10.6.8 when I click on the Apple icon at the top left side of my screen and ten click on about this mac. How can I download Yosemite?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you tried to download Yosemite, and how it was unsuccessful?

Answer (score 2):

Check your iMac model and the date.

In About this Mac (here is mine)

[image: macbook air model]

Yosemite requires iMac (Mid 2007 or newer)

Log in App Store and get it from there. The download process can take very long time, a hour or more (it is > 5 Gig file), depending on your Internet speed.

Once it is done, find the file called "Install OS X Yosemite.app" and click on it.

If Yosemite does not work for you then get the 10.7.5 (minimum required) for TurboTax 2014.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Yosemite OS X  from the App Store. Once the download is completed, the install application appears in your `Applications` folder. You can either go to the `Applications` folder and double click Yosemite and follow the instructions, or go to the `Launchpad` and click Yosemite and follow the instructions.